# Select folder with current date in jBASE

Tags: jbase

Im stuck I have created a folder with current date (e.g test.20160419) and I want select that folder and copy some records in that folder through jBASE command.

Can anyone help me in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [COPY (jBase Knowledgebase)](http://www.jbase.com/r5/knowledgebase/manuals/3.0/30manpages/man/fil2_COPY.htm) command for what you are trying to achieve.

For your specific scenario, assuming that you want to copy all the records from SRC.TABLE table to test.20160419, the command should be:

```
COPY FROM SRC.TABLE TO test.20160419 ALL
```

If you need to copy some of the records in SRC.TABLE you can do a [SELECT (jBase Knowledgebase)](http://jbase.com/r5/knowledgebase/manuals/3.0/30manpages/man/jql2_SELECT.htm) before like so

```
SELECT SRC.TABLE WITH @ID = "A]"
3 Records selected
>COPY FROM SRC.TABLE TO test.20160419 ALL
```

This will copy all the **selected** files (in this case starting with A).